# Static Code Analyzer for taint analysis

Tags: c, static-analysis, dataflow

For an evaluation I need to check the correctness of "dataflow constraints" which describe the relationships between the parameters and return values passed to api function calls. I have the corresponding source files in C / C++.

For example, a code snippet like this:

```
x0 = NtOpenFile(_, 3222274176, _, _, _, 42);
RtlNtStatusToDosError(x0);
```

Would generate the following constraint:

```
NtOpenFile-RtlNtStatusToDosError.0
```

Are there any static code analyzers suitable for this task?

Comment: What is "`taint analysis`"? Is it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taint_checking ?

Comment: @Mawg basically dataflow anaylsis generating lattices describing which value influenced another value